# How to change default values of variables like CC in Makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make, default-value

(GNU) make uses several [variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) like:

- `CC` -- C compiler, by default `cc`
- `CFLAGS` -- flags for the C compiler, by default empty

I would like to specify my own default values of some of them in my `Makefile`. In the example below I used the conditional assignment operator `?=` to be able to override my defaults when running `make`:

```
CFLAGS ?= CFLAGS_my_default
CC ?= CC_my_default

print:
    echo CC=$(CC) CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)
```

Unfortunately this does not change the value of the `CC` variable as the original default value stays there. `CFLAGS` are set by my assignment as the variable was originally empty:

```
$ make print
echo CC=cc CFLAGS=CFLAGS_my_default
CC=cc CFLAGS=CFLAGS_my_default
```

Overriding from environment variables works as expected:

```
$ CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env make print
echo CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env
CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env
```

How can I change the default values of variables and still be able to override them when invoking `make`?

Comment: CC does not have a default value in your own makefile just set it, CC is just a convention for a variable name

Comment: @aaronman: `CC` has value `cc` by default (at least in GNU make I was testing). It is described with the default value in the documentation: [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables). The [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) which use `CC` and other variables are there. For example if you have file `prog.c` and just an empty (!) `Makefile` invoking `make prog` will execute `cc prog.c -o prog`.

Comment: "`CFLAGS` -- flags for the C compiler, by default empty". Well, for me is set by default to `-g -O2`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have used this `Makefile` to run some tests with *GNU Make* and check the [origin](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html#Origin-Function) and default value of some variables:

```
define whatisit
$(info $(1) origin is ($(origin $(1))) and value is ($($(1))))
endef

$(call whatisit,CC)
$(call whatisit,CFLAGS)
```

Here are the results:

```sh
$ make
CC origin is (default) and value is (cc)
CFLAGS origin is (undefined) and value is ()
$ # Environment
$ CC=clang CFLAGS=-Wall make
CC origin is (environment) and value is (clang)
CFLAGS origin is (environment) and value is (-Wall)
$ # Command line
$ make CC=clang CFLAGS=-Wall
CC origin is (command line) and value is (clang)
CFLAGS origin is (command line) and value is (-Wall)
```

As you can see there is two types of variables. These types are defined [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables).

The first set of variables (`AR`, `AS`, `CC`, ...) have `default` values. The second set of variables (`ARFLAGS`, `ASFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, ...) are default to an empty string (i.e. `undefined`).

By default, they can be override by environment or command line.

---

## Set default value for the `undefined` variables

For the `undefined` variables (and also other user variables) you just have to use the `?=` operator to set a default value which can be override by environment or command line.

```
CFLAGS ?= -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

---

## Set default value for the `default` variables

The best way to change default value for the `default` variables is to check for their origin and change the value only when it is needed.

```
ifeq ($(origin CC),default)
CC = gcc
endif
```

---

## Conclusion

The `Makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(origin CC),default)
CC  = gcc
endif
CFLAGS  ?= -Wall -Wextra -Werror

define whatisit
$(info $(1) origin is ($(origin $(1))) and value is ($($(1))))
endef

$(call whatisit,CC)
$(call whatisit,CFLAGS)
```

The final result:

```sh
$ make
CC origin is (file) and value is (gcc)
CFLAGS origin is (file) and value is (-Wall -Wextra -Werror)
$ # Environment
$ CC=clang CFLAGS=-Wall make
CC origin is (environment) and value is (clang)
CFLAGS origin is (environment) and value is (-Wall)
$ # Command line
$ make CC=clang CFLAGS=-Wall
CC origin is (command line) and value is (clang)
CFLAGS origin is (command line) and value is (-Wall)
```

---

## Optional

You can use the `MAKEFLAGS` variable to disable the built-in implicit rules and the built-in variable settings. This way:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR
```

This will clean a lot of default settings (you can check it by using `make -p`). But the `default` variables (like `CC`) will still have a default value.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to use non-conditional assignment:

```
CFLAGS ?= CFLAGS_my_default
CC = CC_my_default

print:
    echo CC=$(CC) CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)
```

but unconditionally set variables cannot be overridden from environment variables:

```
$ CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env make print
echo CC=CC_my_default CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env
CC=CC_my_default CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env
```

Wait, there is another way of setting the variable when invoking `make`! - [from command-line arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding):

```
$ make print CC=CC_from_cmdline CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_cmdline
echo CC=CC_from_cmdline CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_cmdline
CC=CC_from_cmdline CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_cmdline
```

This way the non-conditionally set variables get overridden too. This method even works with recursive use of `make` where the [variables specified on command-line are automatically passed to the new `make` process](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_5.html#SEC52).

Another method is to enable overriding of unconditionally set variables by environment variables using command switch `-e`:

```
$ CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env make -e print
echo CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env
CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env
```

Comment: Unconditionally-set variables can be overridden by environment variables if you invoke make with `-e`: `CC=CC_from_env CFLAGS=CFLAGS_from_env make -e print`

Comment: I added the method to the reply. Thank you!